# How do I redirect signed-in Users attempt to access User.new and User.create in Ruby?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, railstutorial.org

I'm up to the [Chapter 9 Exercises](http://ruby.railstutorial.org/book/ruby-on-rails-tutorial#sec-updating_deleting_exercises) in Hartl's Rails Tutorial.  I've been trying for ages but can't crack question 6:

> Signed-in users have no reason to access the `new` and `create` actions in the `Users` controller. Arrange for such users to be redirected to the root URL if they do try to hit those pages.

First, where should I put these tests?  At the moment I'm trying in `user_pages_spec.rb` but I'm unsure if that's right.  And then where should I put the logic itself?

Second, is this what my test should look like:

```
  describe "after signing-in" do
    before { sign_in(user) }
    describe "creating a new user" do
      before { put new_user_path }
      specify { response.should redirect_to(root_url) }
    end
  end
```

At the moment when I do the above, RSpec tells me

```
Expected response to be a redirect to  but was a redirect to http://www.example.com/signin.
```

But when I test it in my browser, visiting `http://localhost:3000/users/new` with a signed-in user, there is no redirect at all (which makes more sense to me because I haven't coded one).

I've even downloaded Hartl's code from github but I can't see where / if he has included this functionality.

**Edit:**
I've got both

```
 describe "creating a new user" do
   before { visit new_user_path }
   it { should_not have_selector 'title', text: full_title('Sign Up') }
 end
```

And

```
 describe "creating a new user" do
   before { get new_user_path } # note the use of GET here not PUT
   specify { response.should redirect_to(root_url) }
 end
```

to work properly.  Thanks to @Peter de Ridder for help

Comment: More help also [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11118680/hartls-rails-tutorial-chapter-9-exercise-6/11287798#11287798)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not really sure why you have a put request when calling new_user_path.

```
describe "after signing-in" do
  let(:user) { FactoryGirl.create(:user) }
  before { sign_in user }

 describe "creating a new user" do
   before { get new_user_path }
   specify { response.should redirect_to(root_url) }
 end
end
```

Now the test should work as supposed. You still have to write the code to actually do the redirecting. But hey, that's the whole challenge. Personally I would check if a user is signed in/present. If so, new and create actions should no longer be accessible.

Comment: Thanks.  But as shown [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10955474/how-to-test-for-a-redirect-with-rspec-and-capybara), `response` doesn't accept `visit` because it's not an `ActionDispatch::Request`.  Instead I used `it { should_not have_selector 'title', text: full_title('Sign Up') }` just to see if **any** redirection was happening. This test passes but there is no redirect when I do this in my browser.  Any ideas on how to diagnose this seeming mismatch?

Comment: Disregard the question in my first comment.  The tests are working.

Comment: Yeah, I will but maybe it's a good idea if you change `visit` to `get` _or_ change `specify { response.should redirect_to(root_url) }` to `it { should_not have_selector 'title', text: full_title('Sign Up') }`?

Comment: Just did. Was a small mistake when I wrote the test the first time.